# FOSS implementation of IBM MQ protocol

Tags: open-source, message-broker

Is there a FOSS implementation of the IBM's MQSeries (WebSphere MQ) protocol? I mean both client and server implementation/bridge, etc.

I'm aware of an option of running a `wmqJmsClient` profile inside IBM's limited Liberty runtime. However, this covers only the client part.

Is going for the original IBM solution the only option here?